# VBA to Search Using Wild Cards

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to, if possible, create a VBA macro to search the entire column A for any words that contain the letters RU (case sensitive, if possible). I would then like for it to be able to copy those words and paste them on a new sheet starting on A1, then A2, etc. I know how to set the range, but I don't even know how to begin to write the rest. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub RUthere()
    Dim RU As String, N As Long, K As Long, _
        s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, r As Range, _
        v As Variant
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    RU = "RU"
    K = 1
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Set r = s1.Cells(i, "A")
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(1, v, RU) > 0 Then
            r.Copy s2.Cells(K, "A")
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```